# PHP Square of Images

Tags: php

I am trying to create a 10 x 10 square of gif images using PHP. This piece of code is one of doing it but it is insufficient code. I have tried using an if statement but has been ineffective. I am looking for another solution to this problem.

```
<?php

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        echo '<img src="image1.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        echo '<img src="image2.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        echo '<img src="image1.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        echo '<img src="image2.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        echo '<img src="image1.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        echo '<img src="image2.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        echo '<img src="image1.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        echo '<img src="image2.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        echo '<img src="image1.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        echo '<img src="image2.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';
    }
    echo '<br>';

?>
```

Comment: Do you know what method it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you can use only single for loop

```
   $j = 1;
   for($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) { 
    if( $j % 2 == 0){
      echo '<img src="cows.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';
     }
     else{
       echo '<img src="chickens.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px";/>';
     }
    if($i % 10 == 0){       
       echo "<br>";
       $j = $j + 1;
      }
  }
```

Comment: @D Coder Sorry using two images and a 10 x 10 square. I have actually tried doing that

Comment: what you mean you say you want a 10 X 10 square of images

Comment: Example: First line would be 10 images of chickens, second line would be 10 images of cows, third line would be 10 images of chickens and so forth till I have a 10 by 10 square of images. @D Coder

Comment: Thanks for the solution. More efficient code @D Coder